# how to change laravel jobs time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm developing the app for the customer and he wants to start some jobs in special time
I must run it in jobs, that's right?
for example, he wants to publish a post have 2 status published or waiting 
and in send page, he can set time for publish post
how I can develop this in jobs?

```
ScanJob::dispatch($property->Name, $property->Owner, $Scan->id)->delay(Carbon::now()->addHour(Carbon::now()->diffInHours($Time)));
```

it's my first try
get diff time in hours and add it from delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways via which you can solve your problem:

1. Create a Laravel Artisan command(you can use other methods also that Laravel provides, but I found Artisan to be fun and more flexible, helps avoid the rework) and schedule it accordingly.
2. Create a Queued Job and dispatch it for some later time, but it has some limitation like, the Amazon SQS queue service has a maximum delay time of 15 minutes.

Now, what is to be done:

1. In my opinion, you should use Solution 1 as it is more flexible and gives you more control.
2. Queues are used for 2 things. First, ideally, the task you want to perform should be done in the next 30-45 minutes. Second, the task is time intensive and you don't want to block the thread because of that.

Now the **FUN** part.
Note: You need not worry, Laravel will perform the majority of the steps for you. I am mentioning each and every step for the sake of not skipping the knowledge.

*Step 1*: Run the following command to create an Artisan Console Command(Remember to be in your project's root path.):

```
php artisan make:command PublishSomething
```

The command will now be available for further development at `app/Console/Commands`.

*Step 2*: You will see a `handle` method inside the Class like following, this is where all of your logic will exist.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class PublishSomething extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'something:publish';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Publishes something amazing!';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

*Step 3:* Let's add some logic inside our handle method

```
/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->info('Publishing something cool!');
    // you can add your own custom logic here.
}
```

*Step 4*: After you have added your logic, now we need to test it, you can do so like:

`php artisan something:publish`

*Step 5*: Our function is running all fine. Now we will schedule the command. Inside `app/Console` you will find a file `Console.php`, this class is responsible for all task scheduling registration, in our case.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Notice the schedule function here, this is where we will add the schedule logic.

*Step 6*: Now we will schedule our command to run every 5 minutes. You can change the time period very easily, Laravel provides some [pre-made](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options) frequency options, and you have your own custom schedule also.

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('something:publish')->everyFiveMinutes(); // our schedule
}
```

*Step 7*: Now, Laravel's task scheduler itself is dependent on Cron. So to start the schedule, we will add the following file to our crontab.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

That's it! We are done. You have created your own custom command and scheduled it for every 5 minutes.

You can learn more about [Laravel Artisan Command](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan) & [Laravel Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling).

Hope it helps!